# Homebrew size of Cellar

Tags: macos, homebrew

Trying to do cleanup on my system that's running out of space, I found 4 gig in my Cellar directory for homebrew. I am not sure what job the cellar is doing. Is it just a cache that I can safely delete or are those files actually being used?

Comment: Why is this tagged Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Cellar contains what homebrew installs. It then creates symlinks in the /usr/local/bin directory to the files in the Cellar. If you delete what is in the Cellar directory you'll no longer be able to use the stuff homebrew installed.

Comment: This isn't "wrong", but Dimitri has the answer that folks are looking for.  Be sure to look at his.

Answer (score 73):

The cellar directory contains all the packages that homebrew installs.
However it also contains every version that you have installed.

You can run `brew cleanup` to remove old versions of packages to clean some space.

Comment: Is there a way to override a the Stack Overflow owner's accepted answer?

Comment: Wow, this command just freed up 3.4GB of space on my hard drive.

Comment: 10.4 GB on my SSD

Comment: ==> This operation has freed approximately 1.9GB of disk space.

Comment: I have 50GB! Thanks :) ```du -sh /usr/local/Cellar```

Comment: Nowadays /opt/homebrew/Cellar

Answer (score 0):

I guess I shouldn't be kvetching about my 1.4G Cellar.  The cleanup brought it from 1.5 to 1.4.